# How to restart TortoiseGit?

Tags: windows-7, tortoise-git

I have TortoiseGit installed on my Win 7 machine. It generally work very nicely. Occasionally, some of the features seize to work w/o an apparent reason.

For example, normally **TG** will show overlayed icons showing the status of the files and folders in a repo. But sometimes, this feature become inactive. I see only the normal File Explorer icons.

In the settings dialog I set the `Clone...` and `Commit...` as the root context menu items. When right-clicking on a folder in the repo, I see these two options with the entry for the **TG** submenu, and can perform all the normal actions.

But, when right-clicking on a file, I get only the **TG** submenu option, and when opening it, I get a very minimalist actions menu, that normally appears for un-staged files.

Why is this happening?

How can I restart TortoiseGit w/o restarting Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just after posting the question I realized I can try restarting Explorer instead of TG. So, I opened Process Manager and closed the `explorer.exe` processes running there (the executable of Windows Explorer). Then, I selected `File`->`Run...` and typed `explorer.exe` to re-run the process.

This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`ShellExView`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable and then re-enable `TortoiseGit` shell extension. You can also `Restart Explorer` (Ctrl+E) from `ShellExView` -> `Options`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually remember now using this app a long time ago (not for this purpose, though). Thanks for the reminder.